# Django: render radiobutton with 3 columns, cost column must change according to size & quantity selected

Tags: python, django

I need to replicate this form:

https://www.stickermule.com/products/die-cut-stickers

[image]

**A)** In the **Select a Quantity** part there are radiobuttons that show the 1) quantity, 2) price, 3) savings.

I need to know how to construct my model so I can show those 3 values in a single row.

**UPDATE 1**:

I understand that this can be conceptualized as a data table, as first coment suggest.

How can I do that in Django?

How can I design a data table, and generate the radiobuttons in Django?

If I understand correctly datatables is a format for showing data in rows and columns (like excel). How can I do that in Django (plus the radio button tag)? And save that selection in Data Base.

***Context***: I just need to replicate that form for a personal project. No restrictions in anyway :).

**My current model:**

```
class TamaniosCantidades(models.Model):
    TAMANIOS = (('2x2', '2" x 2"',), ('3x3', '3" x 3"',),
               ('4x4', '4" x 4"',), ('5x5', '5" x 5"',))

    CANTIDADES = (('50', '50',), ('100', '100',),
                ('150', '150',))

    # usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tamanios = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TAMANIOS)
    cantidades = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CANTIDADES)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TamaniosCantidadesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tamanios = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TAMANIOS, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label='Selecciona un tamaño')
    cantidades = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CANTIDADES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label='Selecciona la cantidad')
    class Meta:
        model = TamaniosCantidades
        fields = ['tamanios', 'cantidades',]
```

Comment: What is the formula for calculating the price/saving? Updating the displayed prices as the user changes their selection could be done with a few lines of javascript. You should include your current template code, because it's not clear what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 3):

**You are asking too broad question.**

First part is not really a python/django related but rather how to design datatables. If you want to receive a meaningful answer you should put more details and context to your question.

Second question is mostly related to frontend. Take a look into the code of page you gave as an example. Quick peek reveals that savings are calculated in javascript by function called `calculateSavings`

Comment: Kamil, 1) how can I design a data table, and generate the radiobuttons in Django? If I understand correctly datatables is a format for showing data in rows and columns (like excel). How can I do that in Django?

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you want to achieve but let me clarify:

Every size has it's cont per unit. 
Every amount has it's savings per unit.

You want to calculate dynamically cont and saving using these values.

So, first of all you didn't show us your models for costs per size. i.e.

Basically I think you have 2 options for this, easy and hard way, but because it's a broad question I cannot write you down full answer but only give you some hints.

I think first thing is to create sizes and quantities as models and then compose it in something like Order. so something like that:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField()
    cost = models.DecimalField()

class Quantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.CharField() or models.PositiveIntegerField() #it's not important 
    savings = models.DecimalField()

class Order():
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size')
    quantity = models.ForeignKey('Quantity')
```

and now you can create form using ModelChoiceField rather than simple ChoiceField

Easy way:

write your own template for widget where you can use data attributes of radio buttons to calculate easily desired values in additional texts ( cost and savings ). 
You have to write your own template for widgets in first ChoiceField and second seperately.

Hard way: 
Create your own widget with view helper which works kind of like Django Autocomplete Light, so when one or the other radio button is pressed it requests from the server data in json to calculate costs and savings.

I can't write down any of this 2 methods, but I guess this would be helpful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates

Oh, and I absolutely don't know what have dataframes anything to do with it

Comment: excelent, this is indeed what I need. Just the cost shoulnd't be calculated but just call from Size model. As StickerMule does it in the link provided in the question. I'll try your answer.

Comment: I think I need to call the cost part from a model, and calculare the savings with javascript. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think cost models should provide only data, Size->cost per unit, Quantity->discount based on quantity so cost_without_discount=cost_per_unit*quatity cost_with_discount=cost_per_unit*quantity*(1-discount), savings=cost_without_discount-cost_with_discount and you can do it easily with javascript. I would do it that way I think, but that's your choice, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

@Omar - If you dig into the HTML, it is a list embedded within a div. Within that list, it uses a span class. Just do this for each row that you need to add:

```
<li class=" omar-quantity-item">
    <span class="table-cell">
        <input id="quantity_200" name="quantity" readonly type="radio" value"200">
        <label for="quantity_200" class=" quantity">200</label> == $0
    </span>
    <span id="price_200_id" class="table-cell price">$90</span>
    <span class="table-cell savings">Save 61%</span>
</li>
```

Then it is up to you to format this properly using CSS to your liking. Use your web browser's development tools to dig into the CSS and HTML further to get a better idea of how you need to render this inside of a Django template.

As for changing the cost and savings, you need to set up an AJAX event listener for each radio button size select on top, which is probably worth it's own question once you get the bottom div/list setup properly.